# How to set a public variable in someone else's plugin class

Tags: plugin-development, oop

Say there is a class in someone else's plugin that sends mail using `wp_mail()`. It has a public variable for the reply-to address, but it is never set. I am adding the settings field to the WordPress admin via my own plugin and want to set the public variable inside the other plugin's class. Should I extend the class?

This is the existing use of the `$reply_to` variable, but it isn't set and I need to set it. The rest (email, subject, content) is taken care of already. I simply need a way to set this reply-to variable.

```
/**
 * @class Mailer
 */
class Mailer {

    /** @var string e.g. 'John Smith <email@example.org>' */
    public $reply_to;

    function send() {

        if ( isset( $this->reply_to ) ) {
            $headers[] = 'Reply-To: ' . $this->reply_to;
        }

        $sent = wp_mail(
            $this->email,
            $this->subject,
            $this->get_html(),
            $headers,
            $this->attachments
        );

    }

}
```

So my line of thinking is that I need to:

- extend the Mailer class
- write a method to add the new settings fields for reply-to name and email to the existing settings section in the WP dashboard
- write a method to pull the 2 settings/options values from the database and set the variable in the correct format for it to be the string for the reply-to email like this `'John Smith <email@example.org>'`.

Is there a simpler way to set this public variable in someone else's plugin class?

Comment: The original plugin would need to offer you a way to do this via a filter somewhere. You would need to ask its developer. If it ultimately ends up using `wp_mail()` though, then it shouldn't be necessary, because `wp_mail()` itself [has a filter](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_mail/).

Comment: Thanks. I had a feeling that might be the case. Not real fluent in OOP yet. There is indeed a filter I can use and it's actually very simple after all.